# Setting a default value for %sysget return value

Tags: sas

I have the following code:

```
%let my_var = %sysget(MY_VAR);
%put &=my_var;
```

If I run the following code, `my_var` will be defined and print:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

export MY_VAR=1;
/sas/scripts/sas my_script.sas
```

But without that `export` statement, `my_var` is effectively not defined, and the script fully executes, without error.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/sas/scripts/sas my_script.sas
```

I want to set a default value for what's returned from `%sysget` in case the variable isn't defined. How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between an environment variable that is not defined and one that is set to an empty value?  What about one that is set to only blanks?

Comment: I guess just one that is not defined - one that follows the example above of not existing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ENVLEN() function to find the length of an environment variable. It will return -1 when it is not defined.

```
%let vname=MY_VAR;
%let want=DEFAULT;
%if %sysfunc(envlen(&vname))>-1 %then %do;
  %let want=%sysget(&vname.);
%end;
%put &=vname &=want;
```